# Upload selected area as image to server

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I want to create an application (Firefox extension ) which will grab a screen area, save as an image and upload to a server.

Here is my roadmap:

First I will create a *greasemonkey* user script which will be applicable to all domains.
When any page loads, it will add a small button named `screengrab + upload`. 
When the user will clicks the button, it will add a mouse handler so that I can draw a `div` element.

By this resizable `div` element I will select a rectangular area on the web page. On `MouseUp` event I will add a equivalent `Canvas` element over the selected area.

Then I will use `todataurl` function to convert the selected area to an image/png. Now, I want to upload this data to my server. Because my server is different than the domain of the webpage, I need to upload the data (image/png base64 encoded) to the server via cross domain scripting.

For image uploading, I will add a hidden `iframe` from my domain to the webpage. From the webpage, data will be posted to this `iframe` as a variable and then from the `iframe`, data will be posted to my server.

Finally, I will convert the *greasemonkey* script to a FireFox extension using compiler/convert.

Will I be able to make this application in this way?
Please suggest the proper way to do this.

Comment: I have almost made this application. I have used "ScreenGrab" firefox extention and modified its code. This application save image to localfile system. I have upload images using XMLHttpRequest(). As I am using direct Ajax request for upload images. It is valid as Im  requesting from chrome window

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do exactly this. Write your GM script (I suggest [including jQuery](http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/) to make it easier). When you have it working in GM, use the [User Script Compiler](http://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler) to make an extension out of it.